# How to restart apache2 from laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi-tenant package Hyn/Multitenant for laravel and after creating a tenant I need to restart apache2. Within the package, I have a command as:

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

But when this command executes, it throws an error that it can't bind to the port.

So far I have a tried editing visudo with this command:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But it still throws error that it can't bind to port 80.

Comment: Refer: https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/steps-for-configuring-laravel-on-apache-http-server/

Comment: you have  to install suPHP extension for that

Answer (score 1):

php exec() method may help you -

```
exec("/etc/init.d/apache2 restart");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php